# Include jQuery plugin to Angular Universal

Tags: angular, jquery-plugins, webpack, angular-universal

Please help with this issue.

In **[angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)** for importing jquery plugins i'm doing this:
in webpack.config define jquery variables in **ProvidePlugin**:

**jQuery: 'jquery', 
$: 'jquery',**

... and etc.

And in ts component i'm importing the plugin, for example:

```
import 'jquery.backstretch'
```

And all works fine, in console.log it shows the lib.

Can you help what to do in **[angular2 universal webpack](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)???**

i'm doing the same, but when starting

```
dist/server/index.js
```

it throws the error

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/artem/projects/universal-starter/node_modules/jquery.backstretch/jquery.backstretch.js:1472:3)
```

Comment: This is possibly due to jQuery not currently being supported by Universal as there's no `window` object during the prerender context. You can follow [these](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/534) [issues](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/512) to track their progress in adding support for `window` and other browser globals.